# How to make the td different width from up td width? HTML

Tags: html

I have many trs in table.The first tr has two tds,The second tr has four tds.But tds can't align fine between first tr and second tr.Here is my code:

```
<tr>  
<td style="width:20%" id="firTD">appName</td>
<td style="width:80%" id="secTD">micro</td>      
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="width:20%"  id="thirdTD">appPeople:</td>
    <td style="width:80%" colspan="3" id="fourthTD">
        <td colspan="1" style="width:30%" id="fifTD">name </td>
        <td colspan="1" style="width:30%" id="sixTD">company</td>
        <td colspan="1" style="width:40%" id="sevTD">cellphone</td>
    </td>
</tr>
```

What i want:fourthTD width= secTD width,fifTD+sixTD+sevTD width= fourTD width.But acctually,fifTD width=secTD width.It works failed.Who can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`colspan`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp) like this:

```
<tr>
  <td style="width:20%" id="firTD">appName</td>
  <td style="width:80%" colspan="3" id="secTD">micro</td>      
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="width:20%" id="thirdTD">appPeople:</td>
  <td style="width:25%" id="fifTD">name </td>
  <td style="width:25%" id="sixTD">company</td>
  <td style="width:30%" id="sevTD">cellphone</td>
</tr>
```